# unity выдает ошибку при компиляции

Tags: android, unity3d

у меня при компиляции android приложения выходит ошибка Помогите. Что делать?

```
    CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
    D:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe package --auto-add-`overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "D:/Android/android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_`

    stderr[
    AndroidManifest.xml:11: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density').

]

    stdout[
    Configurations:


    (default)
 v14
 v21
 mdpi-v4
 xhdpi-v4


Files:
  drawable\app_banner.png
    Src: (xhdpi-v4) res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png
  drawable\app_icon.png
    Src: (mdpi-v4) res\drawable-mdpi\app_icon.png
  values\strings.xml
    Src: () res\values\strings.xml
  values\styles.xml
    Src: () res\values\styles.xml
    Src: (v14) res\values-v14\styles.xml
    Src: (v21) res\values-v21\styles.xml
  AndroidManifest.xml
    Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

Resource Dirs:
  Type drawable
    drawable\app_banner.png
      Src: (xhdpi-v4) res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png
    drawable\app_icon.png
      Src: (mdpi-v4) res\drawable-mdpi\app_icon.png
  Type values
    values\strings.xml
      Src: () res\values\strings.xml
    values\styles.xml
      Src: () res\values\styles.xml
      Src: (v14) res\values-v14\styles.xml
      Src: (v21) res\values-v21\styles.xml
Including resources from package: D:\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar
applyFileOverlay for drawable
applyFileOverlay for layout
applyFileOverlay for anim
applyFileOverlay for animator
applyFileOverlay for interpolator
applyFileOverlay for transition
applyFileOverlay for xml
applyFileOverlay for raw
applyFileOverlay for color
applyFileOverlay for menu
applyFileOverlay for mipmap
Processing image: res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png
Processing image: res\drawable-mdpi\app_icon.png
    (processed image res\drawable-mdpi\app_icon.png: 94% size of source)
    (processed image res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png: 93% size of source)
    (new resource id app_banner from xhdpi-v4\drawable\app_banner.png #generated)
    (new resource id app_icon from mdpi-v4\drawable\app_icon.png #generated)
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.CompileResources (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Comment: Всю ошибку в студию

Comment: и у меня в assets->plugins->android нету папки res

Comment: там только libs,src, manifest и 2 файла vuforia

Comment: В андроид манифесте не правильно используемые параметры в 11ой строчке. При билде не только файлы из твоего проекта используются, но и внутренние от android sdk и различных aar

Comment: Xumera_hZ 1 можете по подробее опиать что я должен сделать. Я просто новичок в этом. (но и внутренние от android sdk и различных aar ) -> и мне следует отключить их как?

Comment: Сначала билдани без плагинов, отсей проблему на уровне android SDK. Потом постепенно подрубай плагины.